# After an update (a kernel bug it seems) Debian 12 hangs when hitting sudo: Unable to install the new kernel with bug fixed

Tags: debian, kernel, sudo, freeze, bugs

After an update/ upgrade on Debian 12 (weekly update), there is NO WiFi, files are not opening, unable to shutdown or sleep, and freezes when using **sudo**. The bug is fixed with a new release of kernel. But, I am NOT able to install the new kernel.

1. I downloaded the new kernel file to a flash drive using another laptop
2. Copied it to the freezing laptop
3. But on hitting the command:

```
$ sudo apt install ./linux-image-6.1.0-16-amd64_6.1.67-1_amd64.deb
```

terminal freezes without prompting for password.

**EDIT**:

Tried to edit

```
$ nano /etc/default/grub
# GRUB_DEFAULT=0 
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

But it could not be saved since I did NOT use '**sudo**'.
But, when I use *sudo*

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

It freezes without prompting for password (may be because of Network Manager issue)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the trick from **@Jaromanda X** and details from **u/Hendersen43** and

**u/Only_Space7088** at:

https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/18i60wx/networkmanager_service_freezes_the_whole_pc_after/

**I am giving details to help newbees...**:

I solved it by:

(1) Interrupting booting process, and changing the kernel back to the previous version:

While booting, *press F9* to interrupt the booting

Then, use arrow keys on keyboard to *highlight* the previous kernel version and press *ENTER*

(2) Download the patched kernel (linux-image) from the site (from the above reddit posting):

https://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux-signed-amd64/linux-image-6.1.0-16-amd64_6.1.67-1_amd64.deb

(3) Change Directory to Downloads folder (where the image is downloaded)

(4) Installing it using the command (from the above reddit posting):

```
me@debian~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./linux-image-6.1.0-16-amd64_6.1.67-1_amd64.deb
```

(5) Updating and then upgrading to the matching headers (linux-headers)

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt upgrade
```

EDIT: I was unable to make changes in any system file nor install/ remove   kernel, because on hitting '**sudo**' the system hangs without prompting for password.

@GAD3R: Thank you for your detailed answer. But I was unable to make any change in any file or install anything since 'sudo' was disabled.
@garethTheRed: thank you

Answer (score 0):

If installing a new kernel solve your problem, You should install a new `linux-image` from Debian backports, it is easy, fast and secure.

Switch back to an older kernel.

Undo any changes in your grub configuration file.

Adding backports:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main contrib non-free" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -t bookworm-backports linux-image-amd64
```

[Backports instructions.](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2)

[Backports on Debian Wiki.](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports)

Comment: Thank you for your support. But, my problem was the moment I hit 'sudo' , it hangs before prompting for password.

Comment: @A.John check your /etc/hosts file if correctly set or not. Then disable iwd service and wpa_supplicant service.